# How to fetch values in one query object from database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

**I have a DB table like this:**

file_name      owner

file1          owner1

file2          owner2

file3          owner3

****I want to get a db object which will return: filename and owner**

**so far I have tried:****

```
file_name = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

file_vcg_map = [self.session.query(FileownerMapping).filter_by(filename=file) for file in file_name]
```

**but this returning me something like this:**
*[<1>, <2>]*

**and I need:**  *<1>*

*Please help*

Comment: `filter_by` is similar to `WHERE` clause of SQL. so this query will return all columns for matching rows of a table. You've to explicitly fetch desired columns (`<1>`) only and for this you can see docs of your ORM.

Answer (score 0):

If you need one record you can use `first()` method. Something like this

```
file_name = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

file_vcg_map = [self.session.query(FileownerMapping).filter_by(filename=file).first() for file in file_name]
```